# Hypernym for "radio button" and "checkbox"?

Tags: single-word-requests, programming, hypernyms, computing

Dear Ladies and Gentlemen,

Since I'm coding a shared css class for radio buttons and checkboxes, I would like to word it with the appropriate hypernym.

Kind regards

Comment: Were there a good hypernym, jQuery wouldn't have used the name [checkboxradio](https://jqueryui.com/checkboxradio/).

Comment: "Checkables"? "Selectables"? Would you want to include multiple-selection list boxes?

Comment: No. "Checkables" sounds ok, but not perfect.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a specific computing question for, say, Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Fattie This question would be off topic on Stack Overflow. They don't do 'name this thing' questions.

Comment: @Laurel Neither do we.

Comment: A radio button is a checkbox. They are identical. The only thing that distinguishes a radio button is its behaviour with respect to other checkboxes around it.

Comment: How is this question off-topic, while other hypernym requests aren't? Just because the original intention, that caused me to ask this question was, to name a css class?

Comment: @Test123, the blunt reality is WWW and app questions are **just not wanted on here**.  It's a specific, technical, engineering question.  Say someone asked "What's the term for ... " something to do with **bridge building**.  Of course it would just be closed as a field-specific engineering question.  Just because there happens to be a lot of programmers who use SE sites (wave), ELU isn't gonna make an exception for questions about CSS, Swift, c# etc "best names for classes".  It ain't gonna happen.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest one of the following words.

- choice
- selection

"choice", because whether the user is checking a box, unchecking a box, or choosing one item in a radio button list, they are clearly making a choice.  A proprietary programming language used the term "choicelist" for a list with multiple check boxes.

"selection", because Google's [Material Design](https://material.io/) web site calls check boxes and radio buttons "[selection controls](https://material.io/guidelines/components/selection-controls.html)".

Comment: Great answer! I'm personally going to go with "choice", as I have concerns about the potential ambiguity between "selection" and the `<select>` input.

Answer (score 1):

Looking back at the World Wide Web Consortium's XForms specification ([XForms 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xforms/), 2009; [XForms 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xforms20/), 2012), radio buttons and drop-down lists that allow only one choice are renderings of a [`select1` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/xforms20/#The_select1_Element), and check boxes and drop-down lists that allow more than one choice are renderings of a [`select` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/xforms20/#The_select_Element). (Most people don't know how to make multiple selections from a drop-down lists, but both XForms and HTML forms support this.)

So if the hypernym that is being requested here can also cover drop-down lists, I would suggest "select control" or "selection control".

Comment: Thanks, but the word should not include drop-down lists. As for naming the css class, I went with "checkboxradio" for the lack of coming up with a better, equally specific name.

Comment: Again, in case you feel bad about the question being closed: as a software engineer I **obsess to the point of mental disturbance** over the names we use in our codebases for classes - everyone who works for me hates this.  But honestly this site just has **no connection at all** to strings people use in our computer code.  While the answer here is admirable, simply step back and look at the answer, and of course, obviously, it should be on codereview.com, CSS.stackoverflow, www-devs.stackoverflow .. or whatever. I mean it's a discussion of RFCs - heh!!  Utterly no connection to ELU.

Comment: Yes, I can completely understand now. Thanks for making me aware.

Answer (score 0):

I've used quite a few GUI frameworks and libraries, and usually they're most commonly called:
widgets

[List of common generic widgets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_(GUI)#List_of_common_generic_widgets)
[Widget toolkits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit)

> Typically, users interact with information by manipulating visual
>   widgets that allow for interactions appropriate to the kind of data
>   they hold. 
>  [Graphical User Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface)

It's true that the name will vary among different GUI frameworks/libraries/systems. In two of the most popular frameworks, Qt and wxWidgets, as well as nearly every other GUI library I've used calls them widgets. It's true that in technical parlance "control element" may be used." But if you search around I'm pretty sure you'll find them being more often referred to as widgets.

[Comparison of GUIs and widgets supported](http://wiki.ogre3d.org/Comparison+of+GUIs)

In Windows they're generally called controls.

Controls
Button
ComboBox
Date and Time Picker
Edit
List box 
Progress Bar
Scroll Bar
Status Bar
Toolbar
Tooltip
Trackbar

[Windows documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773169(v=vs.85).aspx)

If you do a search for GUI control it will most likely bring you results for "widget"

HTML is the only place I know of where they're referred to as elements. But I have a feeling that's because it's a markup language where nearly everything is an element.

> widget
>   3. Computers a. An element of a GUI, such as a text box or button, that displays information or settings that can be entered or altered
>   by the user.
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/widget)

It's true you won't find this definition in many dictionaries, but I searched for "control" and didn't find anything of the sort. There's no doubt in my mind that they're now most popularly called widgets, though I'm not sure exactly when this happened. All I know is that the word widget was used much earlier than in a computer GUI context. It's been generally used as a placeholder name to mean a "thing.".

If "widget" runs the risk of being misunderstood, then "GUI widget" is a lot clearer.

Edit: I may have misunderstood the question, if you want a word that means either selection box or radio button but doesn't include all the other widgets, then I'd struggle to find a word. As far as I know the difference between a radio button and a checkbox is that you can check multiple checkboxes but only one radio button. The checking of either of these two may be "selection", which Chris Wolfe has already in his answer, or "toggling", as you're marking on and off. Technically toggling might be incorrect because some selection boxes might have three states, not just on or off. Oh, I'm confused.

Comment: Widget should be fine for the OP but I think the literal question is what is a hypernym for checkbox and tadiobutton _and no others_ .

Comment: @Mitch Well technically it is a hypernym, but I get your point. Organism is a hypernym for a trapdoor spider, it's not very specific. Yeah he'd definitely have trouble if he wanted a word specifically for those two.